# List "Slicing" from Python to Django

Tags: python

I have this code to iterate over a limited number of array (list) items:

```
a = ["asd", "asdasd", "foo", "bar"]

for x in a[:3]:
    print x
```

How to slice the numbers of elements when writing it in a django template??

Comment: By which criteria are you excluding your elements?

Comment: @greole numerically. I want only the first X items.

Answer (score 2):

I found it myself:

```
{% for x in element|slice:":3" %} ... {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah, slice cuts the number of elements. Those are called filters. You can create yours. Look at the documentation for more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/